# shell expansion: $(<file) in ansible

Tags: sed, ansible, io-redirection

I have an Ansible playbook which is supposed to replace some characters using stream editor.

```
sed -i "s+foo+$(<replace_file)+g" some_file
```

or

```
sed -i "s/foo/$(<replace_file)/g" some_file
```

cat some_file

```
line one: foo
```

cat replace_file

```
bar
```

expected result

```
line one: bar
```

actual result

```
line one: $(<bar)
```

I have tried the command directly on Ubuntu distro and it works perfectly, but running the command through Ansible gives the error.

Comment: Neither of those first two `sed` commands will work when run directly from the command line; the single quotes inhibit shell expansion so that `$(<replace_file)` is just a literal string, rather than the content of a file named `replace_file`. Running that first command would replace `foo` in `some_file` with the literal string `$(<replace_file)`. Ditto for the second command.

Comment: This is true @larsks, my bad. I was meaning to use `'` instead of `"`. I have gone ahead to edit the post.

Do you have a suggestion on hw I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

The redirection syntax you are trying to use is a Bash feature; if you are running the script using `sh`, it will not work (though I would expect a syntax error rather than what you say in your question that you are getting; it is probably no longer correct after you changed the quotes). See also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash).

Your approach seems extremely brittle, but

```
sed -i "s+foo+$(cat replace_file)+g" some_file
```

should work portably in any POSIX shell.

Comment: I understand that ansible uses ```sh``` instead of ```bash``` so I added

```
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

to instruct ansible to use bash as mentioned in the documentation but that gives me the actual output.

Using ansible's builtin ```sh``` I get a blank character instead of the mentioned output

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ansible but some quick Duck Duck Going suggests that it uses dollar signs for its own variables, so to get a dollar sign passed through to the shell, you need additional shenanigans. Try `\$(` instead of `$(` I guess. The resources I could find say that this depends on which precise context you are in.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to actually use bash as the executable:

```yaml
- shell: sed -i "s+foo+$(<replace_file)+g" some_file
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

Comment: Hello Kelvin, I used the bash executable in my ansible file but I am getting the output I mentioned.

I do not know why this does not work as it is mentioned in the documentation